# Preventing HEIC conversion to JPG when sharing pictures to Gmail app on iPhone

Tags: iphone, photos, gmail, heic

When in gallery and sharing an image via Gmail, it gets converted to a JPG file instead of staying as an HEIC image.

Is there any way to have this behave differently?

Comment: Workaround: share via Mail.app?

Answer (score 1):

A bit roundabout but possible:

1. From gallery, select the photos > tap Share > Save to Files.
2. Go to Files app > tap More (3-dots icon) > Select > select the photos > tap More (3-dots) > Compress. This will zip them.
3. Attach the zip file to Gmail and send. The recipient can download and unzip it to get HEIC images.

Comment: Where is the Files app? How can I open it?

Comment: Files is Apple's file management app on iOS devices.